# Get Token call to Microsoft Graph REST Api gives 400 error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am able to connect to MS Graph API through the Graph Explorer, and using the SDK in C#.  However, when I use the same information as the SDK in Postman, I get a 400 error.  I am POSTing to https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTID/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
(with our tenant id) and using x-www-form-urlencoded to send:

- client_id=OURCLIENTID
- scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
- client_secret=OURCLIENTSECRET
- grant_type=client_credentials

The response is always a 404.

I based this in the [Get Token Request call from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#token-request), so I am not sure why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...I was confused by the formatting on the MS site:

POST [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I was trying to post to [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) HTTP/1.1

when I needed to post to [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)